# Import separate module from relative location in __init__.py

Tags: python, import, module

I know a similar question has been answered ad nauseam in these pages, but I've read all the answers and cannot find a solution that makes my nuanced application work.  The long and short:

I would like to expose an external module (that only exists in a relative path, and I cannot update the PATH variable) to my working module.  In each case, I recognize that I could import the module using a sys.path.append()/import.  However, I would like to import the module in my __init__.py and expose it to the module there (so I only have to adjust the path once, theoretically).  Everything I have read indicates that once I have exposed the module via the import in __init__.py, I should be able to access it via a call like my_module.imported_module.  However, that does not seem to work.  The basic idea is to share a set of functions across multiple modules that should also all be independent.  Example below:

(base module):

```
__init__.py:
import sys
sys.path.append('../') # I know this is not ideal, but for simplicity
import core

myfile:
import base
print dir(core)
```

NameError: name 'core' is not defined

Alternatively:

```
myfile:
import base
print dir(base.core)
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'

And last:

```
myfile:
import base.core
print dir(base.core)
```

ImportError: No module named core

**last, last:

And last:

```
myfile:
import core
print dir(core)
```

ImportError: No module named core

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't really have a choice here, if it's a relative path in a directory outside of your main module, you're going to have to manipulate the path.  You should change your sys.path manipulation to work with `__file__` instead so you aren't bound to current working directly, i.e.:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

However, if the other package shares a package with your file you could use a relative import:

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    core.py
    base/
        __init__.py
        myfile.py
```

You can also do this path manipulation in your `.pythonrc` or with your ipython settings.

Comment: I note that adding the sys.path.append('../'), (or its more pythonic equivalent) in \_\_init\_\_.py does actually allow you "import core" in myfile, provided that the sys.path.append call comes BEFORE the "import myfile" call.  That was my problem.  My example #4 actually does work if these are ordered correctly.

Comment: @drewmiller - right, but if you tried to import your package somewhere else than the toplevel directory for your myfile-containing package, it will break.